# Invisible Documents Folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, hidden-file

I recently built a new PC and migrated my old 2TB HDD with me.
Its basically my `D:`containing all the data while the OS runs on a small SSD `C:`.

On my old system I made all Windows 10 *"Standard folders"* like `\Music` and `\pictures` to be located on `D:`. On my new PC `D:` is now called `E:` for some reason, dont be confused.

I never wiped `D:`/`E:` so all data should still be on it and I just need to reroute my default folders of the newly installed OS on `C:` to the old folders on `D:`. This worked fine for all folders but one.

The one thats missing is the `\Documents` folder. When I try to create a folder called `documents` here, I get a message telling me that a folder with that name already exists here.

[image]

When I use the explorer search function to search for a file of which I know is in the `Documents` folder, it finds the file and if I right click it, the folder and select *"open the path where you are stores"*, Im in the *`\old documents`* folder, where all my data still is. So the folder still exists and is located directly under `E:`, as it is supposed to be.

But it is "hidden/nvisible" and the marker is greyed out to make it visible again.

I googled the issue and found a solutions I tried, but it did unfortunately not work. I ran the command below (**[explained here](https://appuals.com/hidden-attribute-greyed-out-windows-7-8-and-10/))**, but this (even after reboot) changed nothing.

```bash
ATTRIB -H "E:\Dokumente" /S /D
```

System is newly installed and fully updated windows 10. I can give you the other specs but I doubt they are usefull for this issue.

What else could I try? Any suggestion?

Comment: Try taking ownership of the folder:   ...   https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-take-ownership

Comment: Why didn't you just switch the drive-letters so the D stayed the same?

Comment: Documents is a special folder on Windows it’s not meant to be shared across machines or users.

Comment: You should be able to click on "Erweitert", insert your admin passeord and change the status